# cdbl in crystal reports is giving wrong results in decimal points

Tags: crystal-reports

Friends,

This is the formula in the crystal reports 9.

cdbl({nrconsolidated.collamt})/100000.000

nrconsolidated table is having 9 records.

in that one record's collamt value is 154250.

but in the crystal reports output its showing as 1.543 instead of 1.542.
i want only 3 decimal points.i dont know where the mistake is coming from?
in the crystal reports, i clicked on that collamt field and checked the data by seeing the browseData option...its showing as 154250.
how can i solve this issue? its showing the correct value in 4 decimal points but i want only 3 decimal points.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below code will truncate the result after the calculation has been performed, and output it to 3 decimal places. This works for Crystal Syntax and should for Basic as well - I believe it is common amongst both.

truncate(cdbl({nrconsolidated.collamt})/100000.000,3)

On the field set the decimals 1.000 and rounding 0.001 will display what you want.

Comment: so can i use this truncate for all kind of calculations which the user need as 3 decimal points?

Comment: i want to sum the this at the report footer..truncate(cdbl({nrconsolidated.collamt})/100000.000,3) how can i sum this result...if i add sum(truncate(cdbl({nrconsolidated.collamt})/100000.000,3))...its giving error. and again...the results are wrong...manually i calculated the sum(truncate(cdbl({nrconsolidated.collamt})/100000.000,3)), the value is 2621250 but when i divide this by 100000.000 its giving the result as 26.212 the .50 is missing...so the only solution is to show as 4 decimal points?

Comment: @sathyguy To me, it sounds now as if it will be saying the field can not be summed, which is right. First option would be to do this in the data, if possible, as that would allow easier calculations,. the other is the 3 formula trick for manual running totals. Unfortunately I do not have a report open with these in, but it involves adding the value to an array, with a counter. Increment the counter +1 each time and reset the value when needed, and the counter. You will need to redim at 1000 records. Tech republic have an example [link]http://goo.gl/mWCJq[/link]

Comment: @sathyguy, I don't know where your data is coming from, so I am going to assume, maybe wrongly, that it is MSSQL. You could use the round() function. round(field,3,1) should be right. You can try this with an SQL Expression in the report as well. May have more luck with the summing then, too.